# session variables in flask keep changing

Tags: python, flask

I have a very basic flask application that I have deployed to Heroku. I am trying to define a variable that I can change when a specific function is executed. For example, if I have a variable `logged_in=True`, I want to be able to change it to `logged_in=False` when the route `@app.route('/logout')` is executed. Here is the code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, session, request, redirect, url_for, flash, g
from flask import render_template
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.config['logged_in']=True

Session(app)

# Redirect to /login route
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for("login"))

# Open main login page
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST","GET"])
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")

# Verify login credentials
@app.route("/login_check",methods=["POST"])
def login_check():
    return redirect(url_for("main_page"),code=307) if app.config['logged_in']==True else render_template("not_logged_in.html")

@app.route("/main_page", methods=["POST"])
def main_page():
    return render_template("main_page.html",name="Main page")


@app.route("/log_out", methods=["POST"])
def log_out():
    app.config['logged_in']=False
    return redirect(url_for("login"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I launch the app locally, the value of `logged_in` is set to `False` when `logout` is executed and does not change if `login` is triggered again. However, when I deploy the app to Heroku, the value of `logged_in` goes back `True` when `login` is triggered again (it's weird, the value changes sometimes, but not always).

How can I set the value of `logged_in` so that it does not change until I update it with a function? I tried to use `session.config['logged_in']`instead of `app.config['logged_in']`, but I had the same issue. Ideally, I want the value to be unique for each session.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store one value to each session. No sql like `redis` is recommendation.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, session, request, redirect, url_for, flash, g
from flask import render_template
from flask_session import Session
import redis

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'redis'
app.config['SESSION_REDIS'] = redis.from_url('127.0.0.1:6379')
# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.config['logged_in']=True

Session(app)

# Redirect to /login route
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for("login"))

# Open main login page
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST","GET"])
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")

# Verify login credentials
@app.route("/login_check",methods=["POST"])
def login_check():
    return redirect(url_for("main_page"),code=307) if app.config['logged_in']==True else render_template("not_logged_in.html")

@app.route("/main_page", methods=["POST"])
def main_page():
    return render_template("main_page.html",name="Main page")


@app.route("/log_out", methods=["POST"])
def log_out():
    session['key'] = 'False'
    return redirect(url_for("login"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```